# User removal bug - repeated notifications?

Tags: bug, deleted-users, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Is this a bug, or did the Mighty Admins<sup>TM</sup> summarily dismiss 9 people from the site on one day?

[image]

Comment: could be that one user voted on 9 of your posts

Comment: Then there should be one -90 entry?

Comment: can't remember, maybe you're right (I had similar rep losses but it was long ago and I don't remember)

Comment: It was just one user, and the entries are rolled up in your profile... Not sure why they're broken out in the topbar.

Comment: A lot of bugs gets blamed for caching but this one isn't part of that....

Comment: @rene: Really? I thought caching was a deliberate feature.